# Tungstenite read_message stuck on receiving messages

Tags: rust, websocket

I connect to a websocket using the tungstenite crate and it all works fine for a couple of hours. After that the websocket stop sending messages or something and the program gets stuck on read_message waiting for a message to arrive. Does anyone know what is happening or why it is?

I have tried changing the features of tungstenite from rust-tls and native-tls but both seem to produce the same problem after some time.

```rust
loop {
            println!("before read_message");
            let Ok(msg) = socket.read_message() else {println!("Could not read message"); break};
            println!("after read_message");
            let now = Local::now().timestamp_nanos();
}
```

I added the print statements to verify that the read_message is the problem of the program and it indeed keeps the program running, and does not get to the after read_message part.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? Try disconnecting your internet too. Since the remote server never sends a disconnect read_message (now send) never hangs up. I also cannot figure out how to know when the connection is physically down.

Comment: I used the async tungstenite crate and added a time out. This prevents any reason for it to stop getting messages. The websocket i connect sends a lot of messages so a timeout quickly detects if something is wrong and then tries to reconnect. This timeout thing can only be done in the async crate tho.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm discerning. I really wish there was a client-side way to tell if a websocket is "down" when I don't control the server and they don't do pongs. Is it because the async crate allows setting the underlying TCP settings whereas non-async tungstenite does not?

Comment: I only know 2 ways to know if there is still a connection with websockets. 1. Send a message to an endpoint that returns something and checking if that still happens. 2. If you know that a websocket sends information every N seconds. Just setup a timer to reconnect if a message has not been received after a certain amount of time. The async crate of tungstenite allows you to do this in one line of code.


```

Comment: ```rust
pub async fn async_run(&self, tx: Sender<recv_mgs::Message>) -> Result<()> {
        // let server = TcpListener::bind("104.16.171.181:443").unwrap();

        let url = Url::parse("wss://api-pub.bitfinex.com/ws/2")?;

        let (mut socket, response) = connect_async(url).await?;

        while let Ok(msg) = timeout(Duration::from_secs(20), socket.next()).await {

       }
```